# Why do we convert laplacian to uint8 in OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I was working with the laplacian function to detect edges in OpenCV, when I ran into some confusion regarding the underlying principles behind the code.

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/db5/tutorial_laplace_operator.html) features us reading an image with the following code and passing it through the laplacian function.

```
img = cv2.imread("messi5.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
lap = cv2.Laplacian(img, cv2.CV_32F, ksize=1)
```

Now, I am able to understand the code written above pretty well. As I believe, we read in an image, and calculate the Laplacian at each pixel. This value can be bigger or smaller than the original 8-bit unsigned int pixel, so we store it in an array of 32-bit floats.

My confusion begins with the next few lines of code. In the documentation, the image is converted back to an 8-bit usigned integer using the `convertScaleAbs()` function, and then displayed as seen below.

```
lap = cv2.convertScaleAbs(lap)
cv2.imshow(lap)
```

However, my instructor showed me the following method of converting back to uint8:

```
lap = np.uint8(np.absolute(lap))
cv2.imshow(lap)
```

Surprisingly both solutions display identical images. However, I am unable to understand why this occurs. From what I've seen, np.uint8 simply truncates values (floats, etc.) down to unsigned 8-bit integers. So for example, `1025` becomes `1` as all the other bits beyond the 8-th bit are discarded.

Yet this would literally mean that any value of our laplacian for each pixel would become heavily reduced and muddled. If our Laplacian for a pixel was `1024` (signaling a non-zero second derivative in both x and y dimensions), we would instead have the value `0` on hand (singaling a second derivative of zero and a possible local max/min, or in other words an edge). Thus by my logic, my instructor's solution should fail miserably, but surprisingly everything works fine. Why is this?

On the other hand, I do not have any idea about how `convertScaleAbs()` works. I'm going to assume it works similarly as my instructor's solution, but I'm not sure. Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: in opencv it's not truncation but saturation. So every value > 255 becomes 255. Not sure about numpy/python/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV BGR images or Grayscale have pixel values from 0 to 255 when in `CV_8U` 8 Bit which corresponds to `np.uint8`, [more details here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab).

So when you use the [Laplacian](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gad78703e4c8fe703d479c1860d76429e6) function with `ddepth` ([Desired depth of the destination image.](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#filter_depths)) set to `cv2.CV_32F` you get this:

```
lap = cv2.Laplacian(img, cv2.CV_32F, ksize=1)
print(np.amax(lap)) #=> 317.0
print(np.amin(lap)) #=> -315.0
```

So, you need to convert back to `np.uint8`, for example:

```
lap_uint8 = lap.copy()
lap_uint8[lap > 255] = 255
lap_uint8[lap < 0] = 0
lap_uint8 = lap_uint8.astype(np.uint8)

print(np.amax(lap_uint8)) #=> 255
print(np.amin(lap_uint8)) #=> 0
```

Or with any other more straightforward way which does the same.

But you can use also set `-1` as argument for `ddepth`, [see documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#filter_depths), to get:

```
lap = cv2.Laplacian(img, -1, ksize=1)
print(np.amax(lap)) #=> 0
(print(np.amin(lap))) #=> 255
```

In this way you get a wrong result:

```
lap_abs = np.absolute(lap)
print(np.amax(lap_abs)) #=> 317.0
print(np.amin(lap_abs)) #=> 0.0
```